# How to solve Discord Font and Users problem?

Tags: fonts, discord, font-size

I have pproblem with usernames in Desktop Discord software for PC. Please see the attached file.
It should be mentioned that all of the fonts in Mobile app are correct.
How can I fix this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3XRo.png)

I'm searching for solving this problem.